# me podrian indicar o guiar en como se hace esta estructura

Tags: html5, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]cuales son las etiquetas para lograr hacer esa estructura en html si me podrian indicar por favor, soy relativamente nuevo en esto de la programacion entendi al html pero css me confunde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `display: grid`.

(Te recomiendo clickear en `Página completa` despues de `Ejecutar` para ver mejor el ejemplo)

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#contenedor {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 300px;
    grid-template-rows: 150px auto 150px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header"
        "content menu"
        "footer footer";
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    grid-area: header;
}

#content {
    grid-area: content;
}

#menu {
    grid-area: menu;
}

footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}

/*Solo para la demostracion:*/

header, footer, #content, #menu {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    border: solid 1px black;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
      <header>
          Header
      </header>
      <div id="content">
          Contenido
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
          Menu
      </div>
      <footer>
          Footer
      </footer>
</div>
```